# Написать программ, которая распределяет числа по парам

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть числа от 1, 2, 3 ... N ( N <= 500000 ). Написать программу, которая распределяет числа по парам так, чтобы их сумма была простым числом. Не знаю как правильно сделать это распределение, подскажите. Написал как знаю, но походу это вообще не то.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
int i,a;
int A[500000];
 for (i = 1; i <= 500000; i++)
 a = A[i];
 a += A[i + 1];
 if ((a%a == 1) && (a % 1 == 1))
     cout << a;
 system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `(a%a == 1)` - приведите пример, когда это условие будет истинно. Tо же  самое - для `(a % 1 == 1)`.

Comment: Как бы хотел сделать проверку на то, простое число или нет. Извините, что не понимаю.

Comment: прога даже не будет компилироваться.  и еще не вижу смысла в цикле for. скорее всего, он не должен заканчиваться `;`

Comment: *Написать программу, которая распределяет числа по парам так, чтобы их сумма была простым числом.* Что, надо ВСЕ числа использовать? это же NP...

Comment: сложность факториал из тысяч?), или надо первые попавшиеся?.. или может быть там математическое решение..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
bool isprime(int thenumber)
{
    int isitprime = 1, loop;
    for (loop = 3; (isitprime) && (loop<(sqrt(thenumber) + 1)); loop += 2)
        isitprime = (thenumber % loop);
    return(isitprime);
}

#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
void main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int k = 0, n = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 500000;
    std::vector<int> x, primes = { 2 };
    for (int i = 3; i < n * 2; i += 2)
        if (isprime(i)) primes.push_back(i);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) x.push_back(i + 1);
    for (auto i = x.begin(), end = x.end(); i < end; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = i + 1; j < end; j++)
            if (std::binary_search(primes.begin(), primes.end(), *i + *j))
                printf("%7d %7d\n", *i, *j), std::iter_swap(++i, j), j = end - 1, k++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", k * 2);
}
```

для больше чем 10000 остаются лишние цифры, ну может так и надо (ツ)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan - слова того кто уже все понимает и знает, для нас непонимающих все полезно и помогает), если конечно копипастить не будет

Comment: я согласен, но это совсем не тот случай _  тут явно человеку нужны хотябы элементарные знания, а не готовый код